# Problems with ApiDemos install on emulator

Tags: android

I installed every components for android development (Java SDK, Android SDK, Eclipse, etc.) on my Windows laptop and created new virtual device to run APIDemos on it. But when I try do it I get such message:

*Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.apis' in a shell.
Launch canceled!*

As I understand correctly, this bug appears when you try to install new .apk with the same name, but with different signatures. But I created **clean virtual device** without any application, so why do I get this error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uninstalling the previously installed ApiDemos and then install new one.

This apk is already present in the image files of the emulator (sdk). So creating a clean virtual device will also have this installed.

Comment: This helped. But I still don't understand, why didn't this problem appear last time when I launch APIDemos at another PC. Thank you for respond)))